# Is it possible to delete/uninstall the adobe reader add on in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, adobe

For testing purposes I am trying to completely remove the adobe reader addon from IE11 but I don't see how I can do this?
I tried the following but it still appears in IE.
Deleted “nppdf32.dll” from C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\PLUGINS.

Comment: are you trying to do it programmatically? if not, try this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/manage-add-ons#ie=ie-11-win-7 but this appears like a SuperUser question

Comment: Not programmatically, just trying to remove it manually. Tried uninstalling adobe and it is still listed as an add on